# Update a set of included files in ISM file from commandline

Tags: windows, installshield

We have a fairly large sized GWT based WebApplication project for Windows which is packaged using Installshield.
GWT generates javascript and xml files of random names after each compilation. This makes it difficult to generate the Installable package without opening the installShield IDE and manually updating the GWT generated files.

I would like to automate this so that the .ism file is updated with the new .js and .xml file list from the command-line and a complete installer can be generated without having to open the IDE.

I can think of the simple approach of parsing the .ism file and updating it with new names using a custom script, but it will be difficult to make it portable across InstallShield versions; 
Do you know of a simpler and more standard means of achieving this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you targeting Windows Installer or InstallScript as your technology? The former sounds like a poor fit for randomly generated names if you care about traditional upgrades.

Setting upgrades aside, for the needs you mentioned, I would consider using a [Dynamic File Link](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpDynamicFileLinking.htm), especially in an InstallScript project. Or you can consider writing an [automation script](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm).

Comment: Thank you Michael, Dynamic File Link appears to fit my requirements perfectly.